# Highstock 'upColor' is overwritten by series 'color'

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highstock candlesticks. If I specify a `color` for the candlestick `plotOptions` and a color for the `series` data, the `plotOptions` color is overwritten by the `series` color.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
            color: 'blue',
            upColor: 'red'
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'Series name',
        data: ohlcdata,
        color: 'yellow'
    }]
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ew6yna1p/)**

You'll see in the above example that the color of the candlesticks is yellow and not red.

How can I make the `plotOptions` color take priority of the `series` color?

Comment: Which version of Highstock do you use? I can see red color for raising candlesticks and yellow color for falling ones

Comment: @morganfree - Exactly, I'm after red for falling and blue for rising, yet the yellow is overwriting the blue. View the fiddle and remove `color: 'yellow'` to see what I'm referring to.

Comment: Series options takes precedence over plot options. You cannot change this unless you want to modify Highcharts code. I think the most straightforward solution is to configure options for a specific series. http://jsfiddle.net/ew6yna1p/1/